# Using Eclipse milo to create a client for OPC UA but getting error while using the ReadExample

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have built all the jars of the eclipse milo project independently.

```
sdk-client-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
sdk-core-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
stack-client-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
stack-core-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
bsd-parser-core-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

there are no errors in the project. but while running the ReadExample im getting the following error

```
[main] ERROR com.lnt.ClientExampleRunner - Error getting client: Could not 
initialize class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Stack
```

in the

```
stack-core-0.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

i see that Stack class exists.
even if i comment out the

```
Stack.releaseSharedResources();
```

by which it is using the Stack class unable to eliminate this error and connect to OPC UA server.

when the projects of these jar are added in maven dependency it is working fine.
Since i dont need server part of the eclipse milo project trying to thin down the project. Request Help!

Comment: What’s the rest of the error? Are you using JDK 8 to compile and run?

Comment: Yes i am using JDK 8 to compile and run. The rest of the error is as below 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Stack
 at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.config.UaTcpStackClientConfigBuilder.build(UaTcpStackClientConfigBuilder.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient.getEndpoints(UaTcpStackClient.java:560)
 at com.lnt.ClientExampleRunner.createClient(ClientExampleRunner.java:80)
 at com.lnt.ClientExampleRunner.run(ClientExampleRunner.java:106)
 at com.lnt.ReadExample.main(ReadExample.java:35)

Comment: I figured it out it was due to the google collections jar. i had used it instead of Guava jar.